# gesture issue in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uigesturerecognizer, xcode5

I am facing gesture issue which is occurred only in iOS 7. I am adding UIPinchGestureRecognizer on UITextView like this :

```
pinchGestRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scaleTextViews:)];
    pinchGestRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [multipleTextView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGestRecognizer];
```

And in scaleTextViews: method I have written this code:

```
    - (void)scaleTextViews:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestRecognizer1
{
        multipleTextView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale([multipleTextView transform], [pinchGestRecognizer1 scale], [pinchGestRecognizer1 scale]);
        [pinchGestRecognizer1 setScale:1];
 }
```

When I zoom in the textview in iOS 7 and give a color to the text then my textView getting cutoff and changed its position.

[image: Before giving color]
[image: After Giving Color]

Please suggest me what to do.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to change the way a view (in your case a label) is scaled when pinched. You can achieve different scaling types by changing the view layers anchor point.

For your example:
multipleTextView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);

You can play around with anchorPoint, to find the effect that you would like to get.